# How to remove slash trailing only on index.php?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My script is in a directory in my root domain, but always redirect:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/script
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/script/
```

And I would like to remove the trailing slash only in the index.php (homepage) to remove that redirection and if i enter the URL without the trailing slash redirect correctly to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/script
```

My HTACCESS code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
ServerSignature Off
RewriteEngine on

# Force NON WWW TO WWW in all pages.
RewriteBase /script
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/script/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

# Remove the .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# Force the trailing slash at the end of urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# SEO URLs
RewriteRule ^post/([^/\.]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is the connection between the script folder and index.php? Could you give some sample urls for the old situation and the situation you want

Comment: Hello, "script" is the directory of my PHP application, and "index.php" is the homepage that is inside of "script" directory.

Comment: You can disable this automatic slash-adding of mod_dir's with `DirectorySlash Off`

Comment: if I do that my site crash, thanks for the help, i keep trying with the property you told me :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/$ $1 [R,L]
```

It's worked fine on my site.
Since the search result from google is showing the old result before my site upgraded.
lot's of the search result showing

```
homepage.com/property/
```

But with the new website (CMS) the property page couldn't be accessed if there was `/` on the last

So with that code on my `.htaccess` it's been worked like magic.
even if the search result from Google have `/` at the end of the address